# How can I rearange a dataset depending on its results in R?

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataset and I want to rearrange it in order to have more harmony and calculate mean and frequency in an easier way.

Let's take the following example, I have a `dataset` cointaining the last shopping expenditures of different models:

| Observation | Model | Date | Clothing | Price in $ | Store |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # 1 | Amy | 14 / 01 | Top | 60 | X |
| # 2 | Amy | 17 / 03 | SKIRT | 35 | X |
| # 3 | Amy | 05 / 05 | Skirt | 40 | X |
| # 4 | Amy | 05 / 05 | Blouse | 70 | P |
| # 5 | Claudia | 17 / 02 | BLOUSE | 40 | B |
| # 6 | Claudia | 17 / 02 | Jeans | 90 | L |
| # 7 | Claudia | 21 / 04 | Jacket | 120 | L |
| # 8 | Claudia | 22 / 04 | TOP | 30 | X |
| # 9 | Estella | 05 / 05 | NA | 95 | L |
| # 10 | Estella | 07 / 06 | Skirt | 40 | X |
| # 11 | Estella | 08 / 07 | Dress | 150 | H |
| # 12 | Estella | 04 / 08 | Hat | 15 | X |

As you can see some clothing pieces are the same but are written differently (it's on purpose). I want to rearrange this `dataset` in order to keep the models in the exact same order but organize the clothing so that it will always start in alphabetic order and missing values at the end (blouse, dress, hat, jacket, jeans, skirt, NA), regardless of how the word is written. In other words, I want to re-order `Clothing` within each `Model`

I don't have many ideas about what to use as code for this, so I cannot provide a code...

Comment: This should work: `yourDf[order(yourDf$Model, yourDf$Clothing), ]`

Comment: It does the magic but for some reason now `Store` doesn't correspond to the right piece of clothing.

Comment: @Matias V it's always great to include a few lines of your expected output in the question, so that we can clear out the confusion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `sort` only on the `Clothing` column, and put it back to your `df$Clothing`.

```
df$Clothing <- sort(df$Clothing, na.last = T)

   Observation   Model    Date Clothing Price in $ Store
1          # 1     Amy 14 / 01   Blouse         60     X
2          # 2     Amy 17 / 03   BLOUSE         35     X
3          # 3     Amy 05 / 05    Dress         40     X
4          # 4     Amy 05 / 05      Hat         70     P
5          # 5 Claudia 17 / 02   Jacket         40     B
6          # 6 Claudia 17 / 02    Jeans         90     L
7          # 7 Claudia 21 / 04    Skirt        120     L
8          # 8 Claudia 22 / 04    Skirt         30     X
9          # 9 Estella 05 / 05    SKIRT         95     L
10        # 10 Estella 07 / 06      Top         40     X
11        # 11 Estella 08 / 07      TOP        150     H
12        # 12 Estella 04 / 08     <NA>         15     X
```

**UPDATE:** Seems like OP wants to arrange `Clothing` within each `Model`, here's the code for this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Model) %>% arrange(Clothing, .by_group = T)

# A tibble: 12 × 6
# Groups:   Model [3]
   Observation Model   Date    Clothing `Price in $` Store
   <chr>       <chr>   <chr>   <chr>           <int> <chr>
 1 # 4         Amy     05 / 05 Blouse             70 P    
 2 # 3         Amy     05 / 05 Skirt              40 X    
 3 # 2         Amy     17 / 03 SKIRT              35 X    
 4 # 1         Amy     14 / 01 Top                60 X    
 5 # 5         Claudia 17 / 02 BLOUSE             40 B    
 6 # 7         Claudia 21 / 04 Jacket            120 L    
 7 # 6         Claudia 17 / 02 Jeans              90 L    
 8 # 8         Claudia 22 / 04 TOP                30 X    
 9 # 11        Estella 08 / 07 Dress             150 H    
10 # 12        Estella 04 / 08 Hat                15 X    
11 # 10        Estella 07 / 06 Skirt              40 X    
12 # 9         Estella 05 / 05 NA                 95 L
```

Comment: It helps but it doesn't keep the order of the models.

Comment: Based on your statement "keep the models in the exact same order but organize the clothing", I think my solution matched this statement exactly. Or do you want to re-order the `Clothing` within each `Model`?

Comment: @Matias V. See my updated code :)

Comment: Yes, it's what I wanted! Sorry for the misunderstanding. It does the trick but I don't know why now the models are in a different order. I mean Is what I wanted but now I have first observations on Estella, then Amy and then Claudia.

Comment: Maybe your `Model` column is a factor? You can do `mutate(Model = factor(Model, levels = sort(unique(Model))))` before `group_by()` to reorder the factor level alphabetically.

Comment: Is a character, but It doesn't matter, I need to modify my question. As a matter of fact, I wanted to re-order `Clothing` within each `Model` like you could see haha So as long as I have all the observations on the same `Model`but with `Clothing` arranged is good!

Comment: Not your question, but you can clean `Clothing` with `stringr::str_to_title(string = Clothing, locale = "en")`